# How do I get every 6-element permutation with repetition in Python?

Tags: python, permutation

I want to create a list of all possible 6-element permutations from "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789" so for example it should output:

`['aaaaaa','aaaaab','aaaaac'...,'aaaaa0','aaaaa1'...,'aaaaba','aaaabb'...]` and so on.

This is what I tried:

```
import itertools

dictionary = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
print(list(itertools.product(dictionary, repeat=6)))
```

but I ran into a `MemoryError` and then my computer froze up completely, so is there a more efficient way to compute this list?

(I'm using Python 3.8 64-bit)

Comment: The number of permutations is 26^6, so I wouldn’t be surprised at a memoryerror.

Comment: @EricJin **36** (26 letters + 10 digits)

Comment: Yes, and each at 7 bytes per entry if optimized (like writing to a file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how long your list would be? It is 36**6 = 2176782336 items. A bit too much to hold in memory. You should have used a generator:

```
dictionary = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
for x in itertools.product(dictionary, repeat=6):
    print(''.join(x))
```

Comment: According to my calculations it would take approximately 100GB to store this.

Comment: @AllanJuan OTOH a file containing the output of the above code will be only 15GB on Unix/Linux (or 17.5 GB on Windows due to two-byte newlines)

Answer (score 0):

The size of the permutation is huge: 36^6! That's 2176782336 strings. A 6-char string in python is already relatively large due to how python stores separate objects.

```py
from sys import getsizeof

getsizeof('aaaaaa') # 55
```

At 55 bytes per string, the whole list is almost 120 Gigabytes. You probably don't much have memory on your machine.

If you try to convert this iterator to a list, it will generate all permutations at once. What you can do instead is to use the iterator returned by `itertools.product(dictionary, repeat=6)` without converting it to a list.

```py
for s in itertools.product(dictionary, repeat=6):
    # Do something with the string, such as writing it to a file.
```

Without knowing what you are trying to do with the product, I can't specifically tell you how to optimize this. But I can still say that trying to convert this iterator to a `list` is a bad idea.

Comment: Well, there's a [site](https://prnt.sc) which hosts a bunch of screenshots and the way the URLs work is https://prnt.sc/aa0005 following the pattern i described above, so I wanted to try and download the image from every link by iterating through every possible combination, but now I've realized that there's no way my hard disk could store that many images so maybe I'll try just getting a small subsection downloaded